# Angular 2 Route data cannot be recovered in CanActivate

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I was trying to find a way to manage user's role in my angular 2 app without writing a lot of code. I found a solution on the web that has been working fine so far. Consider that I omitted part of the settings to make it less confusing, anyway here are my settings under @NgModule in my module for the routes involved for this particular section of the app:

```
 RouterModule.forChild([
        {
            path: Uris.LogCall,
            component: LogCallComponent,
            canActivate: moduleActivator,
            data: { roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_SUPERVISOR'] }
        },
        {
            path: Uris.ED,
            component: EdComponent,
            canActivate: formActivators,
            data: { roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_SUPERVISOR']  }
        },
        {
            path: Uris.Community,
            component: CommunityComponent,
            canActivate: formActivators,
            data: { roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_SUPERVISOR']  }
        },
        {
            path: Uris.Lab,
            component: LabComponent,
            canActivate: formActivators,
            data: { roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN']  }
        },
        {
            path: Uris.In,
            component: InComponent,
            canActivate: formActivators,
            data: { roles: ['ROLE_SUPERVISOR']  }
        },
        {
            path: Uris.Consult,
            component: ConsultComponent,
            canActivate: formActivators,
            data: { roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_SUPERVISOR']}
        },
        {
            path: Uris.BW,
            component: BWComponent,
            canActivate: BWActivators,
            data: { roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_SUPERVISOR']}
            resolve: { form: BWLFormResolver }

        },
        {
            path: Uris.BWL,
            component: BWLComponent,
            canActivate: BWActivators,
            data: { roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_SUPERVISOR']},
            resolve: { form: BWLFormResolver }
        }
    ])
```

- Uris is a class with static attributes for the URLs.
- CanActivate: in each case they are pointing to a const variable that contains an array with the activators involved.
- The same for the resolve.

Here is the CanActivate in charge of validating roles:

```
    @Injectable()
export class AuthGuardByRole implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private readonly authService: AuthService,
        private readonly router: Router
    ) { }
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        const roles = route.data['roles'] as Array<string>;
        if (roles && this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
            return roles.indexOf(this.authService.User.role) !== -1;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['landing']);
        }
    }
}
```

This works for all until I added the resolve, even though the resolve works properly, the roles variable in the last code in the last 2 cases where the resolve is present is always undefined. But for the rest of the URLs (where there is not resolve) it works perfect, roles is always valid. I mention the resolve because I considered that could be the reason, I am not sure to be honest.

**Resolver**

```
@Injectable() 
export class BWListFormResolver implements Resolve<BWListForm> { 

    constructor(private readonly service: LogService) { } 

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<BWListForm> {
      const id = Number(route.paramMap.get('id')); 
      return this.service.getBWList(id); 
    } 
}
```

I read the documentation and according to my understanding I should receive that value in the data attribute. Any ideas ? Because I have been researching about it a lot in the documentation, doing tests but no proposed alternative works.

I would appreciate help with this.

Thanks in advance,

Luis.

Comment: if this is as you say it is, then it seems to be a bug with angular. `resolve` places it result also in the data object (`data['form']`), but in your case it seems to overwrite it. I'll see if i can reproduce

Comment: What's your angular version and can you post the code of your `Resolve`?

Comment: @PierreDuc , thanks for replying, I'm using angular 4.0.0 / typescript": 2.2.2, in regards to the resolve it works fine there is no issue. Let me see if I can put the code here.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the proper code section, it is more readable then in the comment.

Comment: You are right @Myonara, it was my fault. Thanks for letting me know.